# jquery prevent multiple clicks OR multiple slide toggle to be executed

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.view-details', function () {    
            if (Btn.find('.toggleText').text() === "View seller details") {
                $('#loadingIconRecommendations-' + similarCarId).show();
                toggleViewDetailsBtn($(this));
                shownInterest($(this));
            }
            else {
                toggleViewDetailsBtn($(this));
                hideClasses($(this));
            }
      }
```

I want to disable this click as soon as user has clicked on it once until the complete function is executed.

The function has multiple paths so taking a variable and setting it true initially and false at multiple calls is also cumbersome.

Any other suggestion or way to do this. I tried with .off but it didn't work.

Comment: How does the inner functions work?

Comment: can you provide html or fiddle if possible

Comment: Its bit lengthy. toggleViewDetailsBtn is simple toggling, shownInterest is API call.

Comment: What do you mean by "Disable this click".
Is it an `<a>` tag?
Or do you mean disable it from being ran again until it has completed? (thus, preventing double clicks running it twice)

Comment: Yes i mean to disable it from being ran again until it has completed. I just observed that its creating problem on double click. (may be 2 or more clicks)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to add a class to the element on which the event is registered and exclude this class in the selector:

`$(document).on('click', '.view-details:not(.clicked)', function() {`

And at the end of your function:

`$(this).addClass('clicked');`

So your code looks like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.view-details:not(.clicked)', function() {
      if (Btn.find('.toggleText').text() === "View seller details") {
        $('#loadingIconRecommendations-' + similarCarId).show();
        toggleViewDetailsBtn($(this));
        shownInterest($(this));
      } else {
        toggleViewDetailsBtn($(this));
        hideClasses($(this));
      }
      $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

Note: This will work until the page is refreshed.

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nd1b35om/)**

Comment: Since API call is asynchronous it would add 'clicked' before it has completely executed and code would become re-entrant before 1st click has completed execution.

Comment: @sahil I don't understand exactly what you're trying to achieve. My solution will prevent a second click on the element but is not effecting the general execution of the function.

Comment: When async API would hit, before its success, $(this).addClass('clicked'); would be executed.

Comment: @sahil so just include the `.addClass` inside a success callback of you async API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *prop* method of jQuery to disable your button.
[Check here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
    $(document).on('click', '.view-details', function () { 

                // Disable the button
                $(this).prop('disabled',true)

                /*
                 * Your code here
                 */
                // Enable the button
                $(this).prop('disabled',false) 
          }
```

**Edit:**

Assuming your using Ajax for calling your Api, since the function is executed before the ajax request is completed, in this case you either:

1 - Enable button in Ajax success function

```
$.ajax({
  success : function() {
      $('.view-details').prop('disabled',false);
  }
})
```

2 - Use ajax complete global event

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  // You might want to create function to handle this.
  $('.view-details').prop('disabled',false);
});
```

Comment: Since API call is asynchronous it would enable before 1st click is complete and code would become re-entrant before 1st click has completed execution.

Comment: @sahil I have updated my answer, assuming your using Ajax for calling your Api.

Comment: The solution seems perfect to me but I dont know the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach to the current answers.

You could just use a javascript variable to store if the button has been clicked.

```
//Store if we are running or not
var running = false;
$(document).on('click', '.view-details', function () {
    //Check if we are currently already running this function.
    if(running === false){
        //Set running to true to prevent this function from being called again.
        running = true;
        if (Btn.find('.toggleText').text() === "View seller details") {
            $('#loadingIconRecommendations-' + similarCarId).show();
            toggleViewDetailsBtn($(this));
            shownInterest($(this));
        } else {
            toggleViewDetailsBtn($(this));
            hideClasses($(this));
        }
        running = false;
    }
}
```

This will set it to be running unless you have reached the end of the  on function. This won't work if `toggleViewDetailsBtn` or `hideClasses` are asynchronous.

If it needs to be asynchronous and the call returns a success callback, do something like this:

```
//Store if we are running or not
var running = false;
$(document).on('click', '.view-details', function () {
    //Check if we are currently already running this function.
    if(running === false){
        //Set running to true to prevent this function from being called again.
        running = true;
        if (Btn.find('.toggleText').text() === "View seller details") {
            $('#loadingIconRecommendations-' + similarCarId).show();
            toggleViewDetailsBtn($(this));
            shownInterest($(this), success(){
                running = false;   
            });
        } else {
            toggleViewDetailsBtn($(this));
            hideClasses($(this));
            running = false;
        }

    }
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/heyncwn5/1/) (Inspired and forked from empiric's answer).

Comment: shownInterest is Async and it would fail for that too.

Comment: Do you have a way to know if shownInterest has completed?
Does it return a promise or success callback for example?

Comment: @sahil, i've updated my answer to show how it could work asynchronously.